# What do the Tail Rudders do specifically?

Tags: airplane

What do the tail rudders actually do on airplanes; fighter or commercial? Do they stabilize, turn, or something else?

Comment: [This NASA guide](https://www1.grc.nasa.gov/beginners-guide-to-aeronautics/rudder-interactive/) will help you with any basic questions you should have.